# Group same Date values in a row without changing Column values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, group-by

I have values in multiple rows of a column in the format 'YYYY-MM-DD'and I want to group them all together and visualize the corresponding column values.

```
Date            Col1 
2018-3-8        111 
2018-3-8        8439 
2018-3-8        82429 
2018-3-8         2289
2018-3-9        2810 
2018-3-9        232 
2018-3-9        3287
```

I have to visualize these values as a single day on x axis keeping the corresponding col1 values as it is.

df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month)
I tried this but it gives the attribute error saying "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

I have one more column in the dataset for time in 'Min-sec-msec' format.

Answer (score 0):

The exact expected graph is unclear, but you do not need to `groupby` (this would produce several graphs!).

You can for example use a simple scatter plot:

```
df.plot.scatter(x='Date', y='Col1')
```

Output:

[image: scatter plot with categorical]

If you use a datetime dtype for "Date", matplotlib will take care of the correct spacingif you have unevenly spaced dates:

```
df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).plot.scatter(x='Date', y='Col1')
```

Output:

[image: scatter plot with categorical and datetime]

Reproducible input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('Date': ['2018-3-8', '2018-3-8', '2018-3-8', '2018-3-8', '2018-3-9', '2018-3-9', '2018-3-9'],
                  'Col1': [111, 8439, 82429, 2289, 2810, 232, 3287]})
```

Comment: The plot should be similar the problem I am facing is that it is throwing a keyerror on the column name

eg., The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

  File "/home/s", line 13, in <module>
    df.assign(Date=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])).plot.scatter(x='Date', y='col1')
KeyError: 'col1'

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example and the full traceback? (what are the outputs of `list(df)` and eventually of `df.head().to_dict('list')`?)

Comment: python/pandas is case sensitive `col1` != `Col1`

Comment: This is the output but I think it is throwing error for the name of the column since the name is 'Date' itself ??

[['2015-8-24 ' ' 2:3:59 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.4]
 ['2015-8-24 ' ' 2:3:59 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.4]
 ['2015-8-24 ' ' 2:4:59 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.5]
 ...
 ['2015-8-27 ' ' 4:8:41 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.0]
 ['2015-8-27 ' ' 4:9:41 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.0]
 ['2015-8-27 ' ' 4:10:39 ' 0 ... 0 0 25.0]]

Comment: What is the output of `list(df)`? This should give the list of columns

Comment: I added my reproducible input

Comment: list (df)  is giving the list of columns ! I am facing the same error after using the date column for plotting on x axis

Comment: Yes, I know that's why I asked you to provide the output, as you have a KeyError you're using the wrong column name. Anyway, this starts to become debugging, if you run my code this should work as you want. The KeyError is not directly related to your question ;)

Comment: the code did  help since the dataset is not clear but the output is not clear or I cannot take any results from it anyways.